# Jena parsing issue for freebase RDF dump (Jan 2014)

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, freebase

I am trying to parse freebase dump file freebase-rdf-2014-01-12-00-00.gz (25 GB) using Jena.
There has been many issues reported by Jena regarding bad data.
Example - 150.0 not valid,true and false values not valid 
These issues I have resolved by adding double quotes around decimal and true/false in dump file.
However issues are still being `reported by Jena.(current - org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 161083, col: 110] Illegal object: [MINUS])`

Is there any way to pre process this data so that I don't have to fix each issues one by one.
My Java Code :

```
    // Open TDB dataset
    String directory = "D:/test_dump";
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory);

    // Assume we want the default model, or we could get a named model here
    Model tdb = dataset.getDefaultModel();

    // Read the input file - only needs to be done once
    String source = "D:/test_dump/fixed-freebase-second-rdf.gz";
    FileManager.get().readModel( tdb, source, "N-TRIPLES" );
```

Comment: There's a very recent question on answers.semanticweb.com about this, [Does the Freebase RDF dump conform to the w3 n-triples spec?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26084/does-the-freebase-rdf-dump-conform-to-the-w3-n-triples-spec).  The data is in Turtle, not N-Triples.

Answer (score 4):

The data is in Turtle format, not N-Triples.  They use various Turtle abbreviations (like `true` for `"true"^^xsd:boolean` or number `-27` for `"-27"^^xsd:integer`).

There may still be errors as their dumps have also contained illegal syntax e.g. use of `$` in prefix names without the necessary `\`

Adding quotes around things *changes* the RDF.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: this a copy of my answer from the [answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com) question, [Does the Freebase RDF dump conform to the w3 n-triples spec?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26084/does-the-freebase-rdf-dump-conform-to-the-w3-n-triples-spec)  The short answer is that the data is in the Turtle serialization, not N-Triples.  Turtle support various abbreviations, e.g., `true` for `"true"^^xsd:boolean`.*

Even in the example data on [Data Dumps](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) there's incorrect N-Triples:

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11vjz1ynm>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage.rate> 4.5 .
```

It looks more like their data is in Notation 3 (N3) or Turtle format than N-Triples.  In fact, [this post on the freebase-discuss](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/freebase-discuss/AG5sl7K5KBE/iR7p-YfTNsUJ) from Shawn Simister on 29 August 2013 says (emphasis added):

> I've been working on a new version of
>   the Freebase RDF dumps which will
>   address many of the issues that have
>   been discovered since we first started
>   publishing the data as RDF. …
>   **The biggest change in these dumps is
>   that the format has switched to
>   N-Triples from Turtle.** In practice
>   this a very minimal change since
>   N-Triples is a subset of Turtle which
>   follows the same one-triple-per-line
>   format that we have now.

A [later post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/freebase-discuss/AG5sl7K5KBE/Rk8Btfw8OWQJ) (31 October 2013) touches on the boolean issues:

> Hmm, yeah it appears that this is a
>   bug. Turtle supports true and false as
>   equivalent to "true"^^xsd:boolean and
>   "false"^^xsd:boolean but even though
>   N-Triples is a subset of Turtle it
>   doesn't support the simplified boolean
>   syntax.

It's worth reading more of that thread.  It's a bit frustrating though, because when people are writing things like, "you can just use "true"," it's not clear whether they mean `true`, or `"true"`.  It sounds like some of the people don't actually care about valid RDF so much, or the difference between an untyped plain literal `"true"` and the boolean typed literal `"true"^^xsd:boolean` that can be abbreviated as `true`.  At any rate, the short answer looks like it's "use a Turtle or N3 parser."