# How to read from Java a RDF freebase concept?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, freebase

I would like to read a freebase dump like this from Java:

http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0cycc

I tried to read it from Jena using the following code:

```
    OntModel om = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    om.read(freebaseURL, "N3");
```

But I got an Exception:

org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 34, col: 37] illegal escape sequence value: x (0x78)

Is there a way to..

a) automatically escape these characters? (I found this post, but it seems to be a manual solution, and I need an automatic one: [How to read Freebase RDF data? It seems to be a bit broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779977/how-to-read-freebase-rdf-data-it-seems-to-be-a-bit-broken))

or

b) read the file content using some other API? At the end I want to obtain some concrete values. I think that I can develop a parsing algorithm for this kind of file structure, but if something is already done..

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read Freebase RDF data? It seems to be a bit broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779977/how-to-read-freebase-rdf-data-it-seems-to-be-a-bit-broken)

Comment: If by 'automatic' you mean _programmatic_: it's probably possible to tweak the parser by overriding/extending it to accept/correct broken data. It's certainly possible using Sesame's Rio parser, I would expect it to be possible with Jena as well. It will require some Java programming on your end though.

Comment: Yes, I mean programatically, sorry about the term. I'm trying to make a fix replacing escape characters but is being a bit difficult. I'll check Sesame's Rio parser.

Comment: I've tried to load it from Sesame's Rio parser and with OWL API with no success. It didn't show any error but seems that is not loading the content.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a code that "fix" my current problems. Probably this is not an universal fix (in fact, my fix is adapted to my needs, and in this case the fix makes that some content will be lost.. but for me is ok at this moment).

I attach a link to the code:

https://github.com/alejandrorg/VariousCodes/blob/master/FreebaseFixer.java